# Is it possible to make a slack bot that can read my DMs?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm working on a slack bot that I want to leave an emoji on the message every time the bot is tagged in a message. It works in public channels, but it doesn't work in DMs with other people (or myself).

Is there a special slack scope that it needs to be able to do this? Or is this just a limitation of the platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bots can only read messages in channels/conversations they are members of. There is no scope that will grant the bot permissions to all DMs. Your bot open DMs with other users using `conversations.open` (https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.open).